# Converting vba importdll code to c#

Tags: c#, vba, marshalling, dllimport, fatal-error

I have a vba code that imports a dll.
Here is the code:

```
Declare PtrSafe Function g77alscal Lib "g77alscal.dll" _
Alias "g77alscal_" _
(ByRef Nrows As Long, _
ByRef Ncols As Long, _
ByRef Xinput As Single, _
ByRef MDSout As Single, _
ByRef Metric As Single, _
ByRef Sout As Single, _
ByRef Niter As Long, _
ByRef Xdebug As Single, _
ByRef Idebug As Long) As Long
```

The call in vba is

```
Dim Distance() As Single
Dim MDSout() As Single
Dim Metric(60) As Single
Dim Sout(2) As Single
Dim Niter As Long
Dim Xdebug(5000) As Single
Dim Idebug(30) As Long
Dim ierr As Long

N = CLng(Ncases)


ierr = g77alscal(N, N, Distance(1, 1), MDSout(1, 1), Metric(1), _
                 Sout(1), Niter, Xdebug(1), Idebug(1))
```

In c# i tried to use:

```
[DllImport("g77alscal.dll",EntryPoint="g77alscal_")]
static extern double g77alscal(ref long nRows, 
        ref long nCols,
        ref double xInput,
        ref double mdsOut,
        ref double metric,
        ref double sOut,
        ref long nIter,
        ref double xDebug,
        ref long iDebug
    );
```

And the call to the c# function is:

```
long n1 = Distance.Rows.Count;
long n2 = Distance.Columns.Count;
double n3 = double.Parse(Distance.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString());
double n4 = 0;
double n5 = 0;
double n6 = 0;
double n7 = 0;
long n8 = 0;

double result = g77alscal(ref n1, ref n2, ref  n3,
    ref n4, ref n5, ref n6, ref nIter, ref n7, ref n8);
```

The code passed compiler errors, but it had one runtime error (FatalExecutionEngineError exception).
The error was:

> The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error
>   was at 0x73c36e93, on thread 0x13a0. The error code is 0xc0000005.
>   This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable
>   portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user
>   marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the
>   stack.

I haven't found a documentation for the dll yet, so I can't say much about the dll other than that is a fortran77 compiled code. It is an implementation for the alscal function which is used in spss.

Am I doing something wrong with the definition in c#?
Any help or pointers would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Update:
I have tried to change the code to be as following for the c#:

```
[DllImport("g77alscal.dll",EntryPoint="g77alscal_")]
    static extern int g77alscal(ref int nRows, 
        ref int nCols,
        ref float xInput,
        ref float mdsOut,
        ref float metric,
        ref float sOut,
        ref int nIter,
        ref float xDebug,
        ref int iDebug
    );
```

And the calling:

```
int n1 = 21;
int n2 = 21;
float n3 = float.Parse(Distance.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString());
float n4 = 0;
float n5 = 0;
float n6 = 0;
float n7 = 0;
int n8 = 0;

int result = g77alscal(ref n1, ref n2, ref  n3,
    ref n4, ref n5, ref n6, ref nIter, ref n7, ref n8);
```

In addition, I found another pattern, whenever I run the application with a breakpoint at the code, the error exception above is thrown but when I don't do a debug, an `AccessViolationException` would be thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original "vba version" uses the type `Single` to pass some parameters, which should be a 4-byte floating point number. It's equivalent in C# should be `float`.

What you used in your code is `double` which is an 8-byte floating point number. That caused problems when the function try to clean up the stack and return.

The integer type also seem to have the same problem, where `Long` in vba is 4-byte and C#'s `long` is 8-byte. You should use `int` instead.

Try changing `double` to `float` and `long` to `int`.

Comment: After more tests, the exact error came back again. If not, then there would be a accessviolationexception. Any more ideas?

Comment: @SyakurRahman Are you sure it's the *exact* exception? Maybe it is not the same piece of code?

Comment: Also long in vba is a 4 byte int and is an 8 byte int in c# I believe

Comment: yes it is the same piece of code. I tried to do a statement by statement trace to make sure that the exact line triggered the exception. The error written is exactly as I posted above with the difference of address and error code.

Comment: @DanMetheus so, i should use a int instead of long in c#? Or, since it is required a 4 byte int, would it mean that it needs a type like shortint?

Comment: @DanMetheus Just tried with int, unfortunately it didn't solve the issue. Any more ideas?

Comment: after you make the edits to change your doubles to floats and your longs to int you should repost your calling code.  Also the return value should be int not double or float shouldn't it?

Comment: OK, it seems that I've overlooked the situation for `Long`. Changed my answer.

Comment: @DanMetheus what do you mean by reposting the code? Yes, I have also changed the return value to int. But it still gives the same error. I wonder, could it have anything to do with the values?

Comment: I mean edit your question to show the updated code that defines and calls the dll in c# to reflect that changes you've made.

Comment: Ok now, what about those arrays you're using in your call from vba -- like xdebug(5000), idebug(30), without knowing the dll do you have to provide similar allocations on the c# side?

Comment: What about that: do you know whether you actually need to use pass by reference? Did your vba code actually work?

Comment: @DanMetheus I am not actually sure whether that's a requirement or not, but that's what I found in the vba. The vba itself I got from a friend who used the vba to produce rapfish mesaurements. And yes, the vba code did actually work.